# Can the object call the overriden method instead of its original method

Tags: java, unit-testing

If we have 2 classes like this :

```
public class A {
   public static int m=10;
   public int b(){ m++; return m;}
   public int fun() {
     return b();
   }
}

public class Testfun() extends A {
    @Override 
    public int b() {return 1;}
    public void test(){
       A a = new A();    
       assertEquals(1,a.fun());
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make the method `fun()` in class A call the overriden `b()` instead of the its super `b()`?

The idea is: 
I suppose to test the method `fun()` and do a stub `b()`. So I don't want the method to call the original `b()` and call the stub one.

Comment: Why does `A a = new Testfun()` not work? You can override `b()` in `Testfun` then? If you give it the correct return type of course, the code you posted will hardly compile with `void b() { return 1; } `.

Comment: For stubbing see frameworks suck as [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org)

Comment: @daniu Sorry , I forgot to modify the return type of b() to int instead of void . I edited in now , thanks.

Can I make A a = new Testfun() without overriding all the methods in A class ?

Comment: No, you don't need to override all methods when subclassing. However, you should be very careful when you're testing a class and override existing behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot , that was useful ! . But from your experince, is there any other ways to make and call stubs - without playing in the Tested class - except the overriding way ?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to make the method fun() in class A call the overriden b() instead of the its super b() ?

No way. The instance you have is of type `A` and methods from `A` gets called. Period.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not call.The instance you have is of type A and methods from A gets called.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, because *object* don't know how many of it's childs or are there any of it. When you want to test something inside a class and want to stub it it's signal of you need to make it dependency of the class like this:

```
public class A {
   private final B b;

    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

   public int fun() {
     return b.b();
   }
}

public interface B {
    int b();
}

public class Testfun() {

    public void test(){
       B b = new B {
         public int b() {
             return 1;
         }  
       };   
       A a = new A(b);   
       assertEquals(1, a.fun());
    }
}
```

In this example we make B as dependency of class A and able to change B from desirable implementation in runtime to test dummy in testing. When you need to test B itself you need separate class that tests B. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: The above question is just an example but in reality we can't modify the developer code which is Class A in this example So all I can do is playing in Class Test to use my stubs instead of his methods .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all, it really helped me ! 
My mistake was here

```
       A a = new A();
```

It should be :

```
       A a = new Testfun();
```

Therefor the overriden `b()` will be called.